# Using Hyperledger Fabric in production

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using HF for some time and trying different things regarding business network specification and configuration.

But, I have couple of question regarding best practices (if there are any yet) in using HF in production.

When we talk about using HF in production, should we use docker-compose-base.yaml, docker-compose-cli.yams, cofigtx.yaml.... etc. as files used to setup and configure our business network, and if not, can you please specify what is the best practice use-case?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Docker Swarm/Compose with derivatives of the sample compose files you referenced, or you could use Kubernetes to manage a network (or subset of same). Project Cello is working on delivering such capability. The [Ansible driver](https://github.com/hyperledger/cello/tree/master/src/agent/ansible) in particular has been demonstrated to work effectively - though it is far from a 1.0 level of maturity.

The reality is that you'll want to manage (likely) more than just four peer nodes all on the same VM or host, but manage multiple peers on multiple VMs/hosts even across multiple networks for a production deployment.

Further, you will obviously need to add management and monitoring to the deployed containers for a true production experience. The Hyperledger chat and mailing lists can be good sources of help and insight.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you provide a link to mailing and chat lists please?

Comment: certainly, all are linked from https://hyperledger.org/community - the mailing list for fabric is hyperledger-fabric (of course) and there are multiple channels for #fabric, all beginning with '#fabric-' I would recommend #fabric-kubernetes and #fabric-questions.